# wildcard search with special characters in solr query

Tags: solr

If I search q=searchtext:*xxx*, it works well but if keyword has "-" (q=searchtext:*xxx-xx*) then it does not give result.

Copy all fields in searchtext field and have text_general filed type on it.

Schema:

```html
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
        -->
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" />
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Googling for many hours but could not find a solution.

Appreciate if someone can help.

Edit: changed Keyword tokenizer to Standard

Comment: You are using Keyword Tokenizer which treats the whole field as it is(doesn't break the text on - into smaller tokens) . Then q=searchtext:xxx should not work and q=searchtext:xxx-xx will work if you have text like xxx-xx. Can u verify that your schema is correct.

Comment: Actually using Standard Tokenizer, tried Keyword Tokenizer but then it does not work with searchtext:xxxx so i back it to Standard.

Comment: With Standard Tokenizer, text xxx-xx will break into tokens xxx and xx (break on -). Then you can perform search on xxx, xx . If you want to query over xxx-xx then inside your <analyzer type="query"> you can use Standard Tokenizer itself but not Keyword Tokenizer as it would treat xxx-xx as single field while when indexing we break it into xxx and xx. For reference check https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters

Comment: i understand, so using Standard Tokenizer in bot analyzer index and query..but still i could not find any result for q=searchtext:*xxx-xx*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you [@skm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4703222/skm) and [@Gus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1172174/gus)

I have come out with other solution, might not be the perfect but worked for me.

1. Used Standard Tokenizer
2. Then replaced all special characters

```html
 $keyword = preg_replace('/[\+\-\&\|\!\(\)\{\}\[\]\^\"\~\*\?\:]+/', ' ', $keyword);
```

3. Braked the string by white space and make following query for keyword "dash-issue":

status:1 AND (searchtext:*dash* AND searchtext:*issue*).

Because searchtext contain all searchable text so it works well, it find the document which contain dash-issue and dash and issue in different line or corner.

Answer (score 2):

You say wildcard, though your examples don't seem to include wildcards. Assuming that you are looking for "wild card" search (with the wildcard at the end of whatever is supplied) may find prefix query parser to be helpful. It works like this:

```
q="{!prefix f=searchtext}xxx-xx"
```

You can read more about it [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-PrefixQueryParser). It does no analysis or value transformation, so it often helps with cases that contain spaces or other values that might confuse the standard query parser.

Comment: Is there anything I have to do in solrconfig.xml to use prefix query parser

Comment: After your edit I see that you are looking for infix search which is not quite as easy. However, I'll leave this here for anyone who happens across this while solving the simpler prefix problem